# Create Object with one of constructor's parameter

Tags: java

so I'm   having a lot of trouble understanding how this works...

```
public class Arbitros_modelo {

public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion) {


    // where my  idea   is to create objects with Constructor(String nombre)
            // eg Arbitros_modelo(esteban, colombiano, lateral)

         Object[]  nombre = {nacionalidad, posicion};

}
```

but  this gave me  error,this  is the  idea,  but it does  not work probbly  not  understanding the 
concept   so  can someone  explain to me  o  give me  an article  where i can 
 learn this ?... so did  some  researching and found this:

```
public class Arbitros_modelo {


public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion) {


Object[] Arbitros_modelo.class.getConstructor(Arbitro_modelo.class).newInstance(nombre) = {nacionalidad, posicion}  

}
```

I  know  this is  VERY  wrong  but  just can't  understand  how  to implement this correctly,  please  help.   thanks  !

Comment: you can have global String variables in your class and set them in your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking some parts of OOP.
You must first implement a class which should be able to contain Your data (Person for example) which should have fields (nombre, nacionalidad and position).

Then You probably would like to create a Person object with given parameters using constructors.

The `Object` phrase is not a phrase for class definition. It is a global java class from which all other classes extend.

Still I believe some more information about what You would actually like to do here is necessary.

What is more try revising: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
and 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
public class Arbitros_modelo { 
private String nombre;
private String nacionalidad;
private String posicion;

public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion) {
       this.nombre=nombre;
       this.nacionalidad=nacionalidad;
       this.posicion=posicion;
}
```

Simple

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable name twice, first time as constructor argument:

```
public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion) {
```

Second time as local variable:

```
Object[]  nombre = {nacionalidad, posicion};
```

Just rename it in one of these places and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, then you can use this with a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html),

```
public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre) {
  super(); // <-- be explicit
  System.out.println("Constructor one");
  this.nombre = nombre;
}
public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion) {
  // Object[] Arbitros_modelo.class.getConstructor(Arbitro_modelo.class).
  // newInstance(nombre) = {nacionalidad, posicion}  
  this(nombre);
  System.out.println("Constructor two");
  this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
  this.posicion = posicion;
}
```